# How to explode in php with symbol?

Tags: php

I have string with this symbol **"\"** and i'm trying to explode the string with **"\"** . But explode not working. I have tried with this code.

```
$te="Hello\world";
$ar = explode("\",$te);
echo $ar[0];
```

Hoe can i explode this string ?

Comment: You need to escape the backslash with another backslash

Comment: You didn't notice the parse error when you ran the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape it:

```
$ar = explode("\\", $te);
```

Comment: can u explain me why we should use "\" again ?

Comment: @Harshana See p.s.w.g's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `\` character is used to delimit special characters, known as [escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) (e.g. `\t` for tabs, `\n` for new lines, etc.), so you'll have to escape it if you want to treat it like a literal `\` character:

```
$te="Hello\\world";
$ar = explode("\\",$te);
echo $ar[0]; // Hello
```

It's important to note that although your `"Hello\\world"` string *appears* to have two backslashes, that's actually just the escape sequence for a single backslash.

Comment: Do you really think, that this is the type of questions, that should be answered by 50k+ members?

Answer (score 2):

just double escape it like this:

```
$ar = explode("\\",$te);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape backslashes. This should do what you want:

```
$te="Hello\\world";
$ar = explode("\\",$te);
echo $ar[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code for this code (to well understand what happens) :

```
$te = "Hello\\World";
$ar = explode("\\",$te);
echo $te.'<br/>';
echo $ar[0].'<br/>';
echo $ar[1].'<br/>';
```